# Why did not Worf get court-martialed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Watching DS9 and there is an episode (*Season 5 Episode 7*) where Worf, Jadzia and some others are on a "pleasure planet" Risa.

Worf helps sabotage the weather system for the entire planet and endangers lives of the inhabitants. Later, there seem to be no consequences for his actions.

How can a Federation officer do this and get away like nothing happened?

Comment: "Only Klingon in Starfleet" covers a multitude of sins and Worf knows it.  "Really?  You're going to court martial ME, the ONLY Klingon in Starfleet just because of a little rain?  Wow.  So much for the Federation's diversity." "Um... no, no, no court martial, just, don't do it again, okay?"

Comment: @starpilotsix: Can you really imagine Worf hiding behind that kind of defense?  It's way too blatantly dishonorable.

Comment: Perhaps they realised it was just a bad episode and wanted to forget about it

Comment: What happens on Risa, stays on Risa...

Comment: @Kevin No, it was just a dumb joke.  It was a toss up between that and one where Risa was such an awesome pleasure planet that they realized that Worf's ideal vacation would include rebelling against the very ideal of an ideal vacation and so they planned the whole scenario just so he could have his fun too, and I had more confidence in being able to express the other one coherently at 3am.

Answer (score 4):

In *[Let He Who Is Without Sin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Let_He_Who_Is_Without_Sin..._(episode))*, all Worf does is cause a bit of rain. He leaves Fullerton alone after this. The later Earthquake is caused purely by Fullerton. Not only did Worf play no part in this, he succeeded in diverting it, saving the lives of everyone on Risa.

There was no court martial because Worf was a hero. Yes, he tampered with the weather system and caused a bit of rain, but ultimately he saved the day, and so got let off that minor transgression, assuming anybody found out about it in the first place.

Comment: Yes. On an entire planet. And having broken into the system he then leaves the means to cause more mayhem in the hands of somebody else. So he is negligent as well as being a saboteur. How would you feel if somebody could cause it to Rain all day at your vacation spot that you probably saved for your entire year and you were looking to go visit for almost as long?

Comment: The official Federation report will read that Fullerton was an earthquake-inducing maniac who tried to kill a lot of people, and Worf stopped him, with any mentions of Worf breaking Federation Directives being conveniently left out. So I would probably be very pissed. At Fullerton. Not at Worf. And unless the Federation also watch Deep Space 9, that's how they'll feel about the whole situation as well.

Answer (score 3):

Worf didn't face any punishment because the Risians (bizarrely) don't consider his actions to have been inappropriate.

In their almost pathetic eagerness to please, they seem to be determined to brush his actions, which did, admittedly amount to *little more than a practical joke*, under the proverbial carpet.

> **ARANDIS:** *I hope the two of you will visit Risa again.*
>
> **WORF:** *I did not think I'd be welcome.*
>
> **ARANDIS:** *You still have a lot to learn about my people.*

The fact that he subsequently saved the population from certain destruction almost certainly went some way toward improving his standing.

---

History doesn't record what action was taken against Fullerton and his Bolian accomplice but it can be reasonably assumed that their attempt to murder thousands of people was dealt with rather more harshly.